# Can I call page in sub project from main project in swift IOS?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, subproject

I have two project, one with swift and the other with objective-c. I want to call/change page to my sub project (objective c) from my main project (swift) but it says `Cannot find type 'NameViewController' in scope`.

this is how my project looks like

[image]

and this is the code that I use to call/change view to sub project and get the error

```
let common = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Main") as! NameViewController
```

do anyone have any idea why and how to do the correct way?

Comment: If you are adding the sub project as a framework, you should build the framework/project every time you make a change inside that. 

This changes the framework in the Products folder which you have linked to.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to the top of your code:

```
import FaceMesh
```

Comment: it says `` No such module 'FaceMesh'`` . I already add it in Target Dependencies in Build Phases